# Warning in console using Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components

Well, I'm using Next js 13 to develop a website, but for some reason I'm having this warning in console
`The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate` as `value and it is preloaded intentionally.`

I've tried to remove Links and see if any Image file it's giving problems but any of this helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the

```
 import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
```

Changed this from :

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode}) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

to :

```
import './globals.css'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body >
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

The problem is gone for now! I think in development mode, nextjs preloads css for speedy development and while hot reloading and it does that preloading continuously after every change! Hope to see this problem fixed soon by vercel

Comment: So you're saying you removed the import of the font altogether, but that just renders everything in the default times new roman font, that's not a solution

Comment: We can use styles.css files too and import fonts there using cdn. You do seem to forget that ??? Nextjs comes withmany issues with every new update that you cannot think of lol. IF that solved issue, then it works lol. Its strange but it works both on our sides

Answer (score 1):

I got the same warnings on the repo linked below. Not using anything special but it seems like its something that's getting polyfilled when using the experimental appDir. So don't worry to much about it since I'm sure it will be fixed in the near future!

https://github.com/ShiftCodeEU/shiftcode.eu

Edit: This issue is fixed in one of the more recent canary releases. So if you dont want to deal with this error at the moment you could use canary already or wait for the first coming stable release.

Answer (score -1):

Can you share your code for the polyfill import?
Are you just using a link tag?

It seems like the polyfills are not being called right away so it's telling you there is no need for preload.
Also, if you are using preload, you should use an `as` property.

From [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attributes):

> `as` This attribute is only used when `rel="preload"` or `rel="prefetch"`
> has been set on the  element. It specifies the type of content
> being loaded by the , which is necessary for request matching,
> application of correct content security policy, and setting of correct
> Accept request header. Furthermore, rel="preload" uses this as a
> signal for request prioritization. The table below lists the valid
> values for this attribute and the elements or resources they apply to.

You didn't show us your code, so I assume you are using links to import it? if so, you can probably just remove the `rel="preload"` from your `<link>`

Before:

```
<link href="./static/chunks/polyfills.js" rel="preload"/>
```

after:

```
<link href="./static/chunks/polyfills.js"/>
```

And if you want to keep the preload, you just need to add an `as="script"` to it

```
<link href="./static/chunks/polyfills.js" rel="preload" as="script"/>
```

Comment: Hey Allan! Thanks for your reply. Well, I'm not importing polyfills and I'm using Link component from Next.js

Comment: Well it says in the part that you shared `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js`

Comment: That's why this is strange, because I'm not importing it or anything like that

Comment: @Allan did you got any solution about this issue?

Comment: @Allan I am also getting this error, I'm not using polyfills either (I dont know what they are even)

Comment: @LuisGomezOrtiz, Can any of you provide some way to reproduce this warning?
It's hard to know what it is without some code to look into.